# windows phone create database with items

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

I am building a simple application for windows phone. I want to create a database and want to have several (lets say 10) items in the database. I am a beginner and every tutorial that i have seen is sth about adding items in the database on button "add" or sth like that. I don't need that, because I want to have several item that are in the database, ready for the user to use them. How can I achieve this? Please write to me in a clear way, because I am still a beginner. If you can provide some links of examples or tutorials, that would be great. Thank u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have the preloaded DB then you can Add a sqlCe DB in your application and populate the db with your seed Data.
 then you can copy the DB file to your ISO Store while your Constructor of DBContext is invoked.

```
public Moviadb1DataContext (string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (!iso.FileExists("Moviadb1.sdf"))
        {
            MoveReferenceDatabase();
        }

        if (!DatabaseExists())
            CreateDatabase();
    }

    public static void MoveReferenceDatabase()
    {
        // Obtain the virtual store for the application.
        IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        // Create a stream for the file in the installation folder.
        using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Moviadb1.sdf", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
        {
            // Create a stream for the new file in isolated storage.

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile("Moviadb1.sdf"))
            {
                // Initialize the buffer.
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                // Copy the file from the installation folder to isolated storage. 
                while ((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

you can also add some seed data instead of moving the reference DB if you have very small amount of Data.

```
public ListenDataDataContext (string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        if (!DatabaseExists())
        {
            CreateDatabase();
            List<Audiables> PreLoads = new List<Audiables>();
            PreLoads.Add(new Audiables { Category = 1, Name = "I want To Eat", AudioLocation = "Sounds/Food/1_IwantToEat.wma", ImageLocation = "Images/Food/1_IwantToEat.jpg" });
            PreLoads.Add(new Audiables { Category = 1, Name = "I want To Drink", AudioLocation = "Sounds/Food/1_IwantToDrink.wma", ImageLocation = "Images/Food/1_IwantToDrink.jpg" });

            PreLoads.Add(new Audiables { Category = 2, Name = "I want A Ticket", AudioLocation = "Sounds/Travel/1_IwantATicket.wma", ImageLocation = "Images/Travel/1_IwantATicket.jpg" });
            PreLoads.Add(new Audiables { Category = 2, Name = "I want To Sit", AudioLocation = "Sounds/Travel/1_IwantToSit.wma", ImageLocation = "Images/Travel/1_IwantToSit.jpg" });

            PreLoads.Add(new Audiables { Category = 3, Name = "How Much Is That", AudioLocation = "Sounds/Shopping/1_HowMuchIsThat.wma", ImageLocation = "Images/Shopping/1_HowMuchIsThat.jpg" });
            PreLoads.Add(new Audiables { Category = 3, Name = "Please Take the Money", AudioLocation = "Sounds/Shopping/1_PleaseTakeTheMoney.wma", ImageLocation = "Images/Shopping/1_PleaseTakeTheMoney.jpg" });
            Audiables.InsertAllOnSubmit(PreLoads);
            this.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Happy app making :)

Comment: I got something like this in the App.xaml.cs
using (FoodDataContext db = new FoodDataContext(FoodDataContext.DBConnectionString))
            {
    
                if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
                {
                    //Create the database
                    db.CreateDatabase();
    
                }
            }
and in the Main.xaml.cs I have the onNavigatedTo method there I have stuff that loads up my db but everytime I startup the up the onNagiatedTo method makes the items in the database duplicates the items is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: If you have less data to pre load then use the 2nd method at your app.xaml.cs else you try the 1st methode in the same place

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to check the "Local Database Sample" in the [Windows Phone Code Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)!